# Separate integers in a file by tabs into an array

Tags: c++, file

Honestly, its a file of 200k integers and have no idea how to error check if the way I am doing it is correct so I'd like some help! There are 10 integers per line and 20k lines total.

Here's my code:

```
void readFile(int searchValues[VALUES], string fileName, string fileExtension, string filePath){
    string fileLine;
    ifstream myFile (fileName + fileExtension);
    int currentIndex = 0;
    if (myFile.is_open()){
        while (getline(myFile,fileLine)){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    searchValues[currentIndex] = stoi(fileLine.substr(0, fileLine.find('\t')));
                    fileLine = fileLine.substr(fileLine.find('\t') + 1, fileLine.length()-1);
                    currentIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if there are **always** 10 integers, use `fscanf`. This would be easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for 3 integers ... do the same for 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fl=fopen(argv[1],"rt");
    int a,b,c,line=0;
    while (3 == fscanf(fl,"%d\t%d\t%d",&a,&b,&c))
    {
        printf(
            "line %d contains ints: %d %d %d\n",
            line++,
            a,
            b,
            c);
    }
    fclose(fl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the use of `VALUES`. Also if you're gonna put all the 200k values inside a single array, then why reading only 10 values? I assume you're gonna put each 10 values in a seperate array for example? Anyways, here is a code that reads `VALUES` amount of integers and stores them in an array. Also note that the parameter `filePath` is not used

---

input.txt:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

const int VALUES = 10;

void readFile(int searchValues[VALUES], std::string fileName, std::string fileExtension, std::string filePath){

    if (!filePath.empty() && filePath.back() != '/')
        filePath.push_back('/');

    std::string fullPath = filePath + fileName + '.' + fileExtension;

    std::ifstream input(fullPath);

    if (input.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < VALUES && input >> searchValues[i]) i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[VALUES];
    readFile(arr, "input", "txt", "");

    for (int i : arr)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

---

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```